# Is there a way to search a hashi vault?

Tags: shell-script

`vault list <vault-path>` will show me all the secrets and subdirectories in the given path.

I need to do a recursive search for a secret in a given path and don't see any way to do that with the vault command alone.

Thinking about writing a bash script to do it - but seems like it would need nested arrays, which always make my head hurt.

Is there a tool for searching?  Or has someone already written a bash script or maybe an ansible playbook?

Comment: As far as I know you can't search, guess it's a "security through obscurity" feature. A recursive function should be able to walk the structure, but it might take a while depending on the size and performance of your vault.

Comment: Oh, nice - that's what I ended up doing.  Thanks, your comment would have pointed me in the right direction if I'd seen it sooner.  FYI, it does take a bit.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted. You could improve performance by multithreading, but you would need to do some management of threads to prevent exponential process growth.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!  Self-calling function:

```
#!/bin/bash

function walk
{
local PTH="$1"; shift
local ENTRIES=($@)

for ENTRY in ${ENTRIES[@]}; do
    if [ $(echo "$ENTRY" | grep -c "$SEARCH") -ne 0 ]; then
        echo ${PTH}${ENTRY}
    fi

    if [ "$(echo $ENTRY | grep "\/$")" != "" ]; then
        NEWPTH=${PTH}${ENTRY}
        NEWENTRIES=$(vault list ${NEWPTH} 2>/dev/null | tail -n +3)
        walk ${NEWPTH} ${NEWENTRIES}
    fi
done
}


SEARCH="$2"
PTH="$1"

echo -----------------------------

ENTRIES=$(vault list ${PTH} 2>/dev/null | tail -n +3)
walk ${PTH} ${ENTRIES}
```